# ¿Para que sirve el prototype chain si una propiedad heredada es diferente de la propiedad del objeto del que se hereda?

Tags: javascript

Si tengo el siguiente código:

Cuando una propiedad no existe en el objeto el busca en su proto para ver si existe, pero de que sirve esto?, lo pregunto porque el nombre es heredado pero ese nombre es independiente del nombre del objeto persona, si yo hago cambios en el nombre de empleado no afecta en nada al objeto persona

¿Para que busca la propiedad haciendo prototype chain para ver si la propiedad existe en los otros prototipos si bien una vez se hereda el proto los cambios que se hagan en los atributos heredados no tienen nada que ver con el objeto que esta como prototype de la función

```js
let persona = {nombre:"Juanjo"};

function Empleado(){
  this.salario = 1200.34;
}

Empleado.prototype = persona;

let emp = new Empleado();
emp.nombre = "Sanky Jonathan";

console.log(persona.nombre);
console.log(emp.nombre);
```

Answer (score 0):

Empecemos por que tu tienes un objeto de este modo:

```
let persona = {nombre:"Juanjo"};
```

Posterior hacemos un `prototype` con el método `Empleado` así:

```
Empleado.prototype = persona;
```

Lo que podemos extraer de aquí es que estamos haciendo uso de la cadena de prototipos donde el método `Empleado` ahora será capaz de acceder a las propiedades del objeto `persona`, ya que si generas una instancia de lo anterior de este modo:

```
let empleado1 = new Empleado

console.log(empleado1.nombre)
```

Vas a obtener como salida `Juanjo`

El valor anterior esta declarado en el objeto principal y ahora en la instancia lo tenemos disponible

De hecho aunque la propiedad nombre ya tiene un valor asignado, podemos sobreescribirlo de este modo:

```
console.log(empleado1.nombre = "unomas")
```

> Como dicha propiedad `nombre` ahora esta accesible para `empleado1` es que puedes modificar o consultar su valor.

Entonces.

`nombre` es una propiedad que originalmente existe y depende del objeto `persona` el cual a través del `prototype` permite el acceso a la misma a la instancia que generaste con el método `Empleado` por eso estas en condiciones de obtener el valor original que tiene o modificarlo haciendo la sintaxis de: `objeto.propiedad = valorNuevo`.

**Referencias**

- [Cadena de prototipos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Herencia_y_la_cadena_de_protipos)